# error calling Firebase Functions from Angular7: Response is not valid JSON object

Tags: angular, google-cloud-functions

I am try use firebase functions in angular application.
I use angularfire2 library
In result:

{err: Error: Response is not valid JSON object.
    at new HttpsErrorImpl (http://localhost:4200/vendor.j…}

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const cors = require('cors')({
    origin: true
  });

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    cors(request, response, () => {
        response.send('Hello from Firebase!');
    });

});
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireFunctions } from 'angularfire2/functions';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  message: Observable<string>;
  message2: string;

  constructor(private fns: AngularFireFunctions) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getfsf() {

    this.fns.httpsCallable('helloWorld')({ text: 'Some Request Data' })
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(resp => {
        console.log({ resp });
      }, err => {
        console.error({ err });
      });

  }
}
```

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem. Would like to see if someone has solved it.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I was able to fix it.

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  response.send({ "data": "Hello from Firebase!" });
})
```

It's weird that we need to do it, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

For those where the other answers didn't work, this is what worked for me since I'm using the @angular/fire library and Firebase Hosting to host my angular app:

I had to add a function rewrite to my firebase.json file:

```
  "hosting": {
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/project-name/us-central1/someFunction",
        "function": "someFunction"
      },
      {
        "source": "/project-name/us-central1/anotherFunction",
        "function": "anotherFunction"
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
```

more details can be found here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/functions/functions.md#firebase-hosting-integration